# Clients wants me to "pay myself"

Tags: payments, billing

A client I've worked with in the past who has a habit of paying my invoices on the late side just sent me a photo of their credit card and told me to pay myself "so I don't have to chase them down".

Although this is obviously not the best way to be paid, is it possible?

**I have no idea how to process a card number to add money to my bank or paypal accounts, how can I do it?**

Answer (score 3):

If this is something that you will be doing more often then not. I suggest just saving the CC info on your paypal account. That way all you have to do, when ever you need to pay yourself, is transfer funds from that card to your account.

That's what I do. I have a friend that it's always borrowing money from me and when it's time to pay me back she does the same thing. She sends me  a pic of her debit card and tells me to do it.

Or u can also load your paypal.me account on your web browser, make sure your logged out of paypal, and then just  send yourself a payment from the second person's perspective. Enter the amount you in wasn't to pay your self and then enter credit card info when prompted.

Either way you in will have your payment in minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Many issues could arise, from having to prove I am her with a ZIP code or text message code sent to her phone... Also, these seem to be "hacks" that are borderline legal, and I don't think there's a very legal solution to this so I'll just have to be better at having her pay me the way I want her to... Someone mentioned Square which might be a more acceptable way to do it. Anyways, I appreciate your time and upvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple with PayPal or merchant services...

You merely load the web site and choose send money.. inputting the credit card numbers and any relevant info, setting yourself as the recipient.

Basically the procedure is the same as if you were sending money to someone else. Merely use the client's CC info.

You'll need the CC#, the CSV# on the back, the name on the card and the CC's billing address (at least the zip code).

---

I will often use [Square](https://squareup.com/us/en) while the client is on the phone with me and merely input the numbers they give me. It would be the same process if I merely already had the info.

Comment: No luck so far with PayPal after following your advice! https://imgur.com/a/ShWk0cs

Comment: Do you have a business or personal PP account? You can "request payment" and send yourself an email.. or an email to an account you have access to. That email will have a link to make a payment, which you can do with a CC without any need to log in. I believe you need a PP Business account though. PP assumes "friends and family" aren't randomly sending CC payments without an account. You don't want to be logged into PP when you send the payment.

Comment: I don’t think it’s doable in my situation then. Thanks though!

Comment: It is.. Paypal's just made it more convoluted because they want you to sign up.. See [**here**](https://wise.com/us/blog/how-to-pay-someone-with-paypal) , scroll down to the "without an account". -- Really I use Square for this.. it's been a number of years since I used Paypal this way. For PP I actually have a page on my site using PP's API to generate the payment button and allows for payment without a PP account (i.e. a CC). Kind of a bit more work, but it's possible to set this up on your own site for your own use. One input field (amount) and a continue to PP button....